# How can I add an HTML tag inside a label using Zend Forms?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I am a total newb in Zend, and have to say that working with forms has given me a headache. So I need some help doing this, cause I suppose is better to do this in the framework. So, I have the following PHP code to create a group of radio buttons

```
$this->addElement(
    'radio',
    'paymentmethod',
     array(
       'multioptions' => array('aa'=>'AA','bb'=>'BB','cc'=>'CC','dd'=>'DD','ee'=>'EE'),
       'decorators'   => self::$inputDecoratorTwBsFormRadioBtn,
       'disableLoadDefaultDecorators' => true,
     )
);
```

In my decorators I have the following code:

```
public static $inputDecoratorTwBsFormRadioBtn = array(
 'ViewHelper',
 array(
       'Errors', 
        array('class' => 'alert alert-danger', 'placement' => 'prepend')
 ),
 array(
       array('row' => 'HtmlTag', ),
       array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'form-group-radio-btn')
 ),
);
```

The final result of my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group-radio-btn">
  <label><input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" id="paymentmethod-aa" value="aa">AA</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" id="paymentmethod-bb" value="bb">BB</label><br>

...
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is add a `span` element inside the `label`. So that I have the label like this:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="" id="" value="aa">AA<span></span></label>
```

I have tried the following:

```
$this->addElement(
    'radio',
    'paymentmethod',
         array(
            'multioptions' => array('aa'=>'AA <span> </span>'...
```

But obviously, this approach takes the span element as a text.

Any ideas on how I can add this HTML tag?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to do that by setting `disable_html_escape` option to `true` in your `label` options. Just like this :

```
$this->add(array(
'type'  => 'radio',
'name'  => 'paymentmethod',
'options' => array(
    'value_options' => array(
        'AA' => array(
            'label' => 'AA <span></span>',
            'value' => 'aa',
            'label_options' => array(
            'disable_html_escape' => true,
             )

        ),
        'BB' => array(
            'label' => 'BB <span></span>',
            'value' => 'bb',
            'label_options' => array(
            'disable_html_escape' => true,
            )
        ),
        'CC' => array(
            'label' => 'CC <span></span>',
            'value' => 'cc',
            'label_options' => array(
            'disable_html_escape' => true,
            )
        ),
    ),
),
));
```

**EDIT :**

If the code above doesn't work, you could do something like this in your views :

```
echo html_entity_decode($this->formRow($form->get('element')));
```

The  [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function will converts all HTML tags in the `element` to their applicable characters, like that the html code will not be escaped.

But to make a clean solution,  you should create a custom `FormLabel` and use `html_entity_decode` when overriding `__invoke` function of `FormLabel`.

Haven't tested it, but you'll have something like this :

```
use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormLabel as OriginalFormLabel;

class FormLabel extends OriginalFormLabel
{   
   public function __invoke(ElementInterface $element)
   {
      $res = parent::__invoke($element);
      return  html_entity_decode($res);
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and did not work. But I came around another solution

Comment: So maybe you could post it as an answer

Comment: I created a custom form helper called formRadioSpan wich adds the span inside the label for the radio buttons, then in the user forms I call the helper, that's how I did it